# Unwanted delimiters in Power Query merge

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a single column table called `mergeHeaders` and the header of the table is called `headers`

The table entries are column headers in a power query.

[image]

The merge query merges all the columns in the power query that are in the table on a pipe delimiter `|` and this query works.

But if there are blank or null cells in the Power Query then there are multiple pipes `a||b|c` or `|B|C|` where I want `A|B|C` and `B|C`

[image]

How to prevent these unwanted delimiters

Thanks

```
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Replaced Value2",mergeHeaders[headers],Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"headers")
```

Edit:
I have tried this but it has `no` effect

2nd Edit: actually it does work I just needed to transform all `blank` values to `null` values then it worked fine

```
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Trimmed Text",mergeHeaders[headers], each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"headers")
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue for me by removing empty columns and null-value columns.

```
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source, mergedHeaders, each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(List.RemoveMatchingItems(_, {""}))), "headers")
```

So magic happens with

```
each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(List.RemoveMatchingItems(_, {""})))
```

Thanks Einarr for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple `Text.Combine()`:

```
#"Merged Columns" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "MergedValues", each Text.Combine({[Label],[Title],[Type]},"|"))
```

[image]

---

Or, if you don't want to refer to these headers seperately then:

```
#"Merged Columns" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "MergedValues", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_),Text.From),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I need the table version if this is possible

Comment: @Einarr, not sure what you mean but I edited the answer to include a version that would just join any column in the table regardless of name.

Comment: Thank you JvdV, this did what I wanted `#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Trimmed Text",mergeHeaders[headers], each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"headers")` . I just needed to transform all `blanks` to `null` values